# dynamic attribute value in MVC 3 with razor viewengine

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I write

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@var.ID"/>
```

If I use it, it never works. How can I do it? It's rendered as well as I write in the code.
[image]

It's not worked as well scottgu defined in their blog.

Comment: What is var? Is it part of your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID is from the Model, then you need to use the model keyword

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@model.ID"/>
```

Answer (score 19):

the answer is that

you need to use @() when you need to define in attribute

i know it's my question i never need vote on it.

Comment: I haven't found this to be needed everywhere but for items like id="someString@(model.Id)" is definitely is needed. Thanks for helping me figure that out.